# Deleting topics,subscription, service accounts created using a label in gcloud

Tags: gcloud

I have created a set of topics, subscriptions and service accounts in gcloud. Since this is automated and i am in the dev environment, i would like to tear down this entire setup.

I can do this by individually deleting these resources like below:

```
 gcloud pubsub topics delete projects/<project name>/topics/<topic name>
```

But i was wondering if its possible to associate something like a label while creating these resources so that one can delete the group using this label.

Answer (score 0):

Resources have to be deleted individually in gcloud, and by there respective commands (i.e. you have to delete topics with `gcloud pubsub topics delete`), but you can streamline the process with --format, --filter, piping, and shell utilities. For example, to delete all pubsub topics with the label 'foo' with value 'bar', you can use:

`gcloud pubsub topics list --format="value(name)" --filter="labels.foo:bar" | xargs -l gcloud pubsub topics delete $1`